# VBA - Can you delete a row when the sub housing that command has been called from a different workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have created a massive routine to extract, clean and transform data (dynamically) that I run using a form in a spreadsheet which then outputs that info based on a load of variables. It looks at one of the worksheets (in that same workbook) to get all of the variable data and loops through it as needed.

This works perfectly when run using the workbook the form is in but I am trying to call it from another spreadsheet to create a looped schedule of tasks (which works fine as far as I'm aware)

Is it possible to call a routine in another workbook that contains a line to delete a row? At the moment it runs but blatantly skips over it.

Below is the code and I have thoroughly tested to ensure that all the workbook/sheet/row names are correct using msgbox etc and this code works when run from the workbook it is contained in.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Exceptions").Rows(1).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

I've tried disabling alerts and making the worksheet visible for this section and neither made any difference.

The other strange thing is that it runs this part of the routine twice when it's only called once. When run through the form the routine is only called once and I have tested on the 'calling' workbook to make sure it is not calling this routine more than once (using a msgbox inside the loop) and it is not.

Is there a security function that disables this or something? I've tried many variations but cannot figure it out. I also cannot SELECT worksheets/cells manually this way.

Both Application.ScreenUpdating and Application.Visible are set to FALSE. When calling this routine I have disabled the form.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

To answer some questions this is how I call the routine that is in the other workbook. I use variable pass-through values for most things and I've found the string dates generate properly but don't populate on the other end so I replicate this a second time in the called workbook.

I used a msgbox before and after 'Call_Macro_wb.Close False' to see how many times it calls and and it only shows once so I don't believe it's from this end.

One thing I did fail to mention is that this calls a looped routine in the 'called' workbook that calls another routine also in the 'called' workbook. That function has been working flawlessly for months from the form.

Apologies for not getting everything out as the rest of the code is quite large..

```
Schedule_Details = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule").UsedRange

For x = 1 To UBound(Schedule_Details)

    Function_Name = Schedule_Details(x, 1)
    Workbook_Name = Schedule_Details(x, 2)
    Save_Location = Schedule_Details(x, 3)
    Full_Path = Save_Location & "\" & Workbook_Name

    If Schedule_Details(x, 4) = "1" Then
    'Run [Special] reports here

        'Weekly Figures
        If Schedule_Details(x, 1) = "Weekly Figures" Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now(), 2) = 1 Or Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now(), 2) = 5 Then

                strStartDate = Format(DateAdd("ww", -2, Date - (Weekday(Date, vbMonday) - 0)), "yyyy-mm-dd")
                strEndDate = Format(DateAdd("ww", -2, Date - (Weekday(Date, vbMonday) - 6)), "yyyy-mm-dd")

                Set Call_Macro_wb = Workbooks.Open(Full_Path)

                Application.Run "'" & Workbook_Name & "'!Update_Weekly_Files(" & strStartDate & "," & strEndDate & ",,TRUE)"

                Call_Macro_wb.Close False

                MsgBox "Finished"

            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

That then calls the below

```
Sub Update_Weekly_Files(ByVal strStartDate As String, ByVal strEndDate As 
String, Optional ByVal Bangalore_Flag As Boolean, Optional ByVal 
Auto_Day_Flag As Boolean)

Dim Cust_Name As String, Account_Details As Variant
Dim Clawback_Email As String, Email_Group As String, Save_Location As String, 
Day_Answer As String, WB_Name As String, WB_Name_Suffix As String
Dim strAccount As String, Return_cons As String
Dim j As Long
Dim KPI As Single
Dim BR_Generic As Boolean, Report_Day As Boolean

Account_Details = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current Accounts").UsedRange

If Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now(), 2) = 1 Or 
Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now(), 2) = 5 Then
    Report_Day = True
Else: Report_Day = False
End If

If Auto_Day_Flag = True And Report_Day = True Then

strStartDate = Format(DateAdd("ww", -2, Date - (Weekday(Date, vbMonday) - 
0)), "yyyy-mm-dd")
strEndDate = Format(DateAdd("ww", -2, Date - (Weekday(Date, vbMonday) - 6)), 
"yyyy-mm-dd")

If Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now(), 2) = 1 Then
    WB_Name_Suffix = " (INTERNAL).xlsb"
ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now(), 2) = 5 Then
    WB_Name_Suffix = " (INTERNAL WASH).xlsb"
End If
Else
Day_Answer = MsgBox("Click 'Yes' to update the RAW figures or 'No' to update 
the FINAL figures", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Please choose an action")

If Day_Answer = vbYes Then
    WB_Name_Suffix = " (INTERNAL).xlsb"
Else
    WB_Name_Suffix = " (INTERNAL WASH).xlsb"
End If
End If

For j = 2 To UBound(Account_Details)

If Account_Details(j, 5) = "y" Then
DoEvents

    Cust_Name = Account_Details(j, 1)
    strAccount = Account_Details(j, 2)
    Return_cons = Account_Details(j, 3)
    Save_Location = Account_Details(j, 4)
    Clawback_Email = Account_Details(j, 6)
    KPI = Account_Details(j, 7)

    If Left(Cust_Name, 3) = "StM" Then
        Cust_Name = "StM"
    ElseIf Left(Cust_Name, 3) = "UBT" Then
        Cust_Name = "UBT"
    ElseIf Left(Cust_Name, 3) = "HDM" Then
        Cust_Name = "HDM"
    ElseIf Left(Cust_Name, 3) = "Ine" Then
    Cust_Name = "Inenco"
    End If

    WB_Name = "Performance Report - " & Cust_Name & WB_Name_Suffix

    Call QueryException(Cust_Name, strStartDate, WB_Name, strEndDate, 
strAccount, Return_cons, Save_Location, Clawback_Email, KPI)

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now(), 2) = 5 Then
        If Account_Details(j, 9) = "y" Then
            If IsEmpty(Cust_Name) = True Then
                MsgBox "Didn't work homie"
            Else
                If Account_Details(j, 10) = "y" Then
                    BR_Generic = True
                Else: BR_Generic = False
                End If

                Call Extract.Extract_Data(Cust_Name, strStartDate, 
strEndDate, "W", BR_Generic, Clawback_Email, True)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
Next

Application.Cursor = xlDefault
Application.Visible = True

MsgBox "~ Finish ~ " & Auto_Day_Flag

If Auto_Day_Flag = True Then
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: how are you calling it - can you show that code aswell?

Comment: @QHarr I've added in more code but it's not lining up properly due to the width restrictions. All blocks are closed and if you don't see a '_' assume it's one line.

Comment: typo? ==> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).RowS(1).Delete

Comment: @EvR Ah yes sorry a typo when I wrote it here but it's correct in the code. I'll amend this now in my example. Thanks for the pickup!

Answer (score 0):

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Row(1).Delete  will delete row 1 in the first worksheet of the workbook that hosts the code. If you want to delete a row in another workbook you need to specify that workbook

```
  Workbooks("AnotherWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets(1).row(1).delete
```

Note that if you have file extensions hidden you need to check that the file is actually called that and not .xlsm etc.

Comment: ThisWorkbook actually changes when my first routine calls the second workbook. I've double checked this by running a msgbox on ThisWorkbook.name. I have also tried the same with ActiveWorkbook to the same effect. This is further proved as nothing is deleted in any workbook unfortunately.